# Spring transactions - using two transaction managers(one within other)

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am using Spring transactions (@Transactional). I am using two transaction managers. For ex

```
 @Transactional(value="tx1")
   public  void approve(){
      createSomething();
  }

 @Transactional(value="tx2")
  public void createSomething(){
 }
```

where tx1 nd tx2 are two different transaction managers managing two different data sources. However tx2 doesn't seem to work. What can be the issue. I am getting the data from first data source and inserting in the next.Its in the insert part, I want the transaction management to work. The first transaction manager manages some other data source which I am not really concerned about. How can I make second transaction manager work

Comment: First the method isn't public, second it is an internal method call which doesn't pass through the proxy . Basically it doesn't add any value.

Comment: I have made it public..even then it doesn't work

Comment: Have you actually read my comment? It will not work in your current setup regardless the visibility.

Comment: Ok. So how do i make it work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Put the method in a different service and call it from your other method...